# How to solve this async/await error (CoreData)?

Tags: swiftui, async-await

I am new to Core Data and I'm trying to create a notes app.My project builds but when I try to add a note it crashes.  I'm a newbie to using async/await, and there's not many explanations online, so I don't understand the compiler error I have.

It says "No 'async' operations occur within 'await' expression".

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Note.name, ascending: true)])
    var notes: FetchedResults<Note>
    
    @State private var NoteIds: Set<Note.ID> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(notes, selection: $NoteId){ note in
            Text(note.name)
        }
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction){
                Button(action: newNote){
                    Label("New Note", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func newNote(){
        Task{ await newNote(name: "New Note", text:"")}
    }
    private func newNote(name: String, text: String) async {
        await viewContext.perform {           //where error is 
            let note = Note(context: viewContext)
            note.id = UUID()
            note.name = name
            note.text = text
        }
        try? PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

PersistanceController:

```
final class PersistenceController{
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    
    lazy var container: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Notes")
        container.loadPersistentStores {description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
            }
        }
        return container
    }()
    
    private init() {}
    
    public func saveContext(backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil) throws {
        let context = backgroundContext ?? container.viewContext
        guard context.hasChanges else {return}
        try context.save()
    }
}
```

Comment: `perform`, while technically an asynchronous operation, does not use *Swift's* `async/await`. Because it doesn't use `async/await`, there's nothing to `await`

Comment: What is the alternative to perform then?

Comment: You don't need an alternative. Just omit the `async` and `await` keywords. You may have to do your `save` operation inside the `perform` (I'd double check that -- I'm not a CoreData expert)

Comment: I have still not figured it out. I am using Big Sur. Could that potentially be the problem?

Comment: The operating system version doesn't have anything to do with whether `perform` uses `async/await`.

Comment: By getting rid of async/await and task the app is not able to create a new note. Adding "try? PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()"inside viewContext.perform does not help. Before I've seen you can use await with perform so I'm not sure why it's not working with async.

Comment: You are likely supporting an unsupported os version. See my answer below `async await` is available in more os versions than `await viewContext.perform`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your projects only supports

**iOS 15.0+
iPadOS 15.0+
macOS 12.0+
Mac Catalyst 15.0+
tvOS 15.0+
watchOS 8.0+
Xcode 13.0+**

I want to emphasize the versions `async/await` is Swift and is supported by more platform versions than the Core Data method.

With a basic project provided by Xcode this works in the `ContentView`

```
private func addItem() async{
    do {
        try await viewContext.perform {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            try viewContext.save()
        }
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/3802018-perform

From WWDC [Bring Core Data Concurrency to Swift and SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017)

Answer (score 1):

The view context is on the main thread you don't need async/await. Here is the sample addItem from Xcode's Core Data app template:

```
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I pass parameters to this Add function? Like in my original example, I want to pass in name and text.  I reformatted my newNote function to the Core Data (addItem) template and added my original attributes, but my code will still not create a "new note" when the button is pressed.

Comment: You shouldn't need params for that. You could create a  `@State` struct `NewNoteConfig` that has the attributes, use a `sheet` with text fields to edit them, and use the struct inside an `addNote` function. If you want to make a convenience Note init then that should go in the Note managed object extension that the model editor can create for you.